# Move from Haswell to Broadwell CPU caused ping utility to fail on sendmsg()

Tags: linux-kernel

I have a Intel dual socket Haswell 18 core server where ping command works, but when I replaced the Haswell with Intel dual socket Broadwell 22 core CPU the ping command fails with -EFAULT "Bad address".  I used strace utility and found the sendmsg arguments looks a little different.  I then looked at the ping.c source and with gdb found the sendmsg returns EFAULT.  I checked the sendmsg arguments on a Haswell and Broadwell CPU server with the same Linux OS and found no differences.  I am starting to believe that the kernel needs rebuilt for the Broadwell processor. Could the Broadwell have something different that causes sendmsg to fail in the kernel layer. Can anyone offer any explanation?